# Iteration to get variables below target value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, scipy, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a code that both calculates two contaminant levels and iterates w.r.t to one of the inputs to get them below their respective targets. There's a huge amount of code before the contaminants are calculated, so it would only be messy if I shared the entire code. I'll try my best with some pseudo-code/snippets of the calculations instead.

```
# pseudo inputs.

a = 10.0; b = 5.0; c = 15.0
d = 0.5; e = 1.0

# pseudo outputs
contaminant_1 = a * b + c
contaminant_2 = a * d + e

# target values
contaminant_1_target = 10.0
contaminant_2_target = 2.0
```

I want the code to use the input `a` to iterate in order to get `contaminant_1 < contaminant_1_target` and `contaminant_2 < contaminant_2_target`. Any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: What do you mean by iterate when `a` seems to be a single value?

Comment: I want the input `a` to be an iterable input, not just a constant value. I'm just stuck at this point.

Comment: how is it supposed to iterate? You have to define some rules for what values you want to iterate over.

Comment: if you want to iterate then first you would need list with many values `for a in [..., ..., ...]:` or use some function to generate many values `for a in range(100):` OR use `while`-loop and change `a` inside this loop.

Comment: it looks like method used in `machine learning`. You have to run `while`-loop which calculate `contaminant_1` `contaminant_2`, compare them with `contaminant_1_target` `contaminant_2_target` and if comparition is wrong then change `a` (increase or decrease with some value) and repeat all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate to find value `a` which met conditions then you would need `for`-loop or `while`-loop and change value `a` in this loop

```
a = 10.0
b = 5.0
c = 15.0
d = 0.5
e = 1.0

# target values
contaminant_1_target = 10.0
contaminant_2_target = 2.0

step = -0.1  # precision

while True:
    # pseudo outputs
    contaminant_1 = a * b + c
    contaminant_2 = a * d + e
    #print(contaminant_1, contaminant_2)
    
    if contaminant_1 < contaminant_1_target and contaminant_2 < contaminant_2_target:
        print(a)
        break
    else:
        a += step
```

---

**EDIT:**

But if you use wrong `step` then it may calculate in wrong direction and it will run forever. It would need to check if current value is bigger than previous value and make correcion.

It looks similar to `machine learning` and `linear regresion` which
use [Least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) to find matching function

it compares `(contaminant_1 - contaminant_1_target)^2` with previous value to see if it has to change direction.

---

**EDIT:**

Version which compare current and previous `(contaminant_1 - contaminant_1_target)^2` and change `step = -step` - and it can start with `a` below or above result.

(Wikipedia: [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares))

```
# - constants -  `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`

B = 5.0
C = 15.0
D = 0.5
E = 1.0

# - variables - `lower_case_names`

a = 1.0
#a = 10.0

# --------------------------------

# target values
contaminant_1_target = 10.0
contaminant_2_target = 2.0

step = -0.1  # precision

# at start it should be rather `infinity`
previous_LS_1 = 0  # least squares
previous_LS_2 = 0  # least squares

while True:
    # pseudo outputs
    contaminant_1 = a * B + C
    contaminant_2 = a * D + E
    #print(contaminant_1, contaminant_2)
    
    # ---

    current_LS_1 = (contaminant_1 - contaminant_1_target)**2
    current_LS_2 = (contaminant_2 - contaminant_2_target)**2

    if current_LS_1 > previous_LS_1 and current_LS_2 > previous_LS_2:
        print('change direction:', a)
        step = -step
        
    previous_LS_1 = current_LS_1
    previous_LS_2 = current_LS_2

    # ---
        
    if contaminant_1 < contaminant_1_target and contaminant_2 < contaminant_2_target:
        print('a:', a)
        break
    else:
        a += step
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion seems to work, however, only if my initial guess for `a` was slightly above the required value to get `contaminant_1 < contaminant_1_target`. Do you have a suggestion on how I can implement `machine learning` or `linear regression` in my code?

Comment: if you have `a`  below then you have to use `>` instead of `<`. You may keep previous  result and compare `(contaminant_1 - contaminant_1_target)^2` with previous `(previous_contaminant_1 - contaminant_1_target)^2` - if new value is bigger then you have to change direction (decreasing `a` instead of increasing - `step = -step`)

Comment: I added code which compares `(contaminant_1 - contaminant_1_target)^2` and change `step = -step` and it works for `a` below and above result.

Comment: last version need different method to check if it should exit. So it needs stil modification

Comment: after tests it think it would need little different method. at start calculate first `contaminant_1` and `contaminant_2` and: (1) if they are bigger than expected value then decrease `a` until you get `contaminant_1` and `contaminant_2` smaller than expected value, (2)  if they are smaller than expected value then increase `a` until you get `contaminant_1` and `contaminant_2` bigger than expected value, and get previous result,